# Python Queue get()/task_done() issue

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

My consumer side of the queue:

```
m = queue.get()
queue.task_done()

<rest of the program>
```

Questions:

1. Does `task_done()` effectively pops `m` off the queue and release whatever locks the consumer has on the queue?
2. I need to use `m` during the rest of the program. Is it safe, or do I need to copy it before I call `task_done()` or is `m` usable after `task_done()`?

be happy

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No, `queue.get()` pops the item off the queue. After you do that, you can do whatever you want with it, as long as the producer works like it should and doesn't touch it anymore. `queue.task_done()` is called only to notify the queue that you are done with something (it doesn't even know about the specific item, it just counts unfinished items in the queue), so that `queue.join()` knows the work is finished.

Comment: does `task_done()` affect `qsize()`? That is, if the Queue has a size limit, when does it consider the slot "empty", after `get()` or after `task_done()`?

Comment: The slot is freed up after `get()`, `task_done()` is just an utility above the queue level, it does not really work with the queue itself.